# HTML5 Video Only Plays Back at fast speed on Ubuntu/Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, html5

Every html5 video I try to play online plays at double/1.5x speed (very useful when trying to fastforward through a video, not great otherwise).  I can slow it down to half speed (e.g. on YouTube HTML5 player), but can't get it back to normal.

The weirdest part is that it's not just one browser: it's every browser on my computer. (and clearing cache, etc doesn't really help). Flash video still works fine.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 (specifically Lubuntu, but I'm guessing it doesn't make a difference).

Answer (score 6):

Took me days to figure out the issue, but basically `pulseaudio` can get screwed up and somehow cause all html5 video to go wonky.

Easy fix:

1. Stop pulseaudio:

   `killall pulseaudio` (or) `pulseaudio -k`
2. Restart pulseaudio

   go to `Run` (Alt+F2) and type `pulseaudio` (or run `pulseaudio` in a terminal)

And this weird error will magically be fixed.